# How to put a google login in react?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to put google login in react based app.But I could not finding a proper way how to do this.I used npm packages but somehow it failed.Can you provide a basic example of doing this? thank you.

Comment: This is a super generic question, do you have more specific examples of what actually fails? What other libraries/frameworks you're using and tried that didn't work? A quick google gave me this as an example: https://github.com/meta-meta/webapp-template/blob/6d3e9c86f5c274656ef799263c84a228bfbe1725/app/Application/signIn.jsx

Comment: url is "http://localhost:8080/#/login?_k=p3s7r1"   error is:"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'refine' of undefined"   on  var cursor = this.props.cursor.refine('account', this.getRoute());

Comment: thank u for example but if u could me a little additional help to deal with error?because i am new in reactjs